# Yii2 session array with pagination

Tags: jquery, arrays, session, pagination, yii2

Hello I have problem with storing session array with pagination. I make web shop and I have shop page where I have some stuffs for selling, on "buy" button I set ID for every item in DB. And I need to make 1 array that's working okay with pagination so I can use those IDs in the "cart" so the user can view what he actually bought. Here is my view with the items for selling:

```
<?php foreach ($stock as $stocklist): ?>
    <div class="col-sm-4"> 
        <div class="prod_box">
            <div class="product_title"  value="<?php $stocklist->name ?>" >  <?php echo $stocklist->name ?> </div>
            <div class="prod_price"  value="<?php $stocklist->price ?>">   <?php echo $stocklist->price ?>  $ </div>
            <div class="prod_buy">
                <button type="submit" value="<?= $stocklist->id ?>" class="custombtn" method='post'  title="Add to Cart" > Buy </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I use also JS (Ajax) to send to the controller every item that is bought and I'm putting every ID in array:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var IDs = [];
        $('.custombtn').click(function () {
            var id = $(this).attr("value");
            IDs.push(id);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '<?php echo Url::to(['stock/shop']); ?>',
                data: {IDs},
                dataType: 'json'
            });
            console.log(IDs);
        });
    });
</script>
```

And in the controller I have:

```
public function actionShop() {

    Yii::$app->session->open();
    $session = Yii::$app->session;

    $query = Stock::find();
    $pagination = new Pagination([
        'defaultPageSize' => 6,
        'totalCount' => $query->count(),
    ]);
    $stock = $query->orderBy('id')
            ->offset($pagination->offset)
            ->limit($pagination->limit)
            ->all();

    if (Yii::$app->request->post()) {

        $session = Yii::$app->session;

        $data = Yii::$app->request->post();

        $session['lastIDs'] = $data;
    }

    return $this->render('shop', [
                'stock' => $stock,
                'pagination' => $pagination,
    ]);
}
```

So with :

```
$session['lastIDs'] = $data;
```

I save all IDs in the session but when I switch the page with pagination and click on more stuff to buy the items ID are overwritten. I try also to make 2 session variables and to merge arrays but then it saves all the API calls so I have 20 arrays for 20 "items" bought and every array have +1 ID that was clicked as last, not only 1 array with all the IDs that were bought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ReWritten in  JS :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.custombtn').click(function () {
            var id = $(this).attr("value");
            console.log(id);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '<?php echo Url::to(['stock/ajax']); ?>',
                data: {id: id},
                dataType: 'json'
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Make also actionAjax where :

```
public function actionAjax() {

    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
        Yii::$app->session->open();
        $session = Yii::$app->session;
        if (!isset($session['selectedItems'])) {
            $session['selectedItems'] = [];
        }

        $allItemsIDs = $session['selectedItems'];
        $itemID = Yii::$app->request->post("id");
        $allItemsIDs[] = $itemID;
        $session['selectedItems'] = array_unique($allItemsIDs);

        return "OK";
    }
}
```

and actionShop remain :

```
 public function actionShop() {


    $query = Stock::find();
    $pagination = new Pagination([
        'defaultPageSize' => 6,
        'totalCount' => $query->count(),
    ]);
    $stock = $query->orderBy('id')
            ->offset($pagination->offset)
            ->limit($pagination->limit)
            ->all();

    return $this->render('shop', [
                'stock' => $stock,
                'pagination' => $pagination,
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Worked With:**

$(document).ready(function() {

```
var IDs = [];
$('.custombtn').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("value");
    IDs.push(id);
    console.log(IDs);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?php echo Url::to(['stock/shop']); ?>',
        data: {
            data: IDs
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    });
});
```

});

Comment: The problem is in the controller because I cant save the IDs in one array from different page when I use pagination

Answer (score 0):

then try this

public function actionShop() {

```
if (!Yii::$app->session->isActive) {

    Yii::$app->session->open();

    $query = Stock::find();
    $pagination = new Pagination([
        'defaultPageSize' => 6,
        'totalCount' => $query->count(),
    ]);
    $stock = $query->orderBy('id')
            ->offset($pagination->offset)
            ->limit($pagination->limit)
            ->all();


}
return $this->render('shop', [
            'stock' => $stock,
            'pagination' => $pagination,
]);
```

}

Comment: I think I must save the array in the session , so I can use it in the cart and checkout page , with what u write u open just a session but not save arrays . There is no saving "values" in session with what u write